# Eloquent where clause to use related model's column when using with() -laravel 4

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have 2 models

**Truck**

```
class Truck extends \Eloquent {
    // Add your validation rules here
    public static $rules = [
        'trucktype_id' => 'required',
        'weight'=> 'required',
        'truck_no'=> 'required'

    ];

    // Don't forget to fill this array
    protected $fillable = ['trucktype_id','weight','picture_path','remarks','truck_no'];

    public function TruckType(){
        return $this->belongsTo('TruckType','trucktype_id');
    }
}
```

**TruckType**

```
class Trucktype extends \Eloquent {
    // Add your validation rules here
    public static $rules = array(
                    'type'         => 'required|unique:trucktypes,type',
                    'max_weight'   => 'required'
                );

    // Don't forget to fill this array
    protected $fillable = ['type','max_weight'];
}
```

I need to lookup related table records i.e `TruckType`

```
$trucksobj = Truck::with('TruckType');
if($truck_no!="")
    $trucksobj->where("truck_no",'=',$truck_no);
if($start_date!="" && $end_date!="")
    $trucksobj->whereBetween('created_at', array($start_date, $end_date));
if($truck_type!="")
    $trucksobj->where("trucktype_id",'=',$truck_type);
if($overweight=="on")
    $trucksobj->where('TruckType.max_weight', '>=', 0);
```

But the above query didnt resolve `TruckType.max_weight` and throws following error

**SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'TruckType.max_weight' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `trucks` where `TruckType`.`max_weight` >= 0)**

Comment: what about using `having` instead of `where` in the last statement?

Comment: i havent used aggregate function here .. so  no point of using having

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand how `with()` actually works. It is only used to alleviate the [N+1 query problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-issue), and **does not** make the contents of the table available for querying. After your first query has ran to select all of the trucks, the `with()` simply causes the following query to be automatically ran:

```sql
select * from TruckType where TruckType.id in (...)
```

Here the list at the end will contain all of the different `truck.trucktype_id` values that were found in your first query, and then they'll automatically be available for you to use via `$truck->TruckType->{property}` etc.

Now, if you actually have a look at the query that's being generated for you, you can clearly see that there is no TruckType table referenced anywhere:

```sql
select count(*) as aggregate from trucks where TruckType.max_weight >= 0
```

This is why the error is being thrown.

---

You have two options:

**(1) Use a join**

```php
$trucksobj = Truck::with('TruckType')->join('TruckType', 'truck.trucktype_id', '=', 'TruckType.id')->where('TruckType.max_weight', '>=', 0);
```

**(2) Use `whereHas()` to place a constraint on your relationship**

```php
$trucksobj = Truck::with('TruckType')->whereHas('TruckType', function($q) {
  $q->where('max_weight', '>=', 0);
});
```

If you don't actually need to know anything about the truck type, and you only want to use it to sieve through the trucks, then you can get rid of `with('TruckType')` and just keep the rest of the query.